# lift disabling back button actions

Tags: scala, lift

I'm creating a transaction related site using lift. In here, there's a requirement to show a success page after the user action.
when i make action happen and press the **browser's back button**. it again goes to the previous page(before transaction page) making the transaction doable again. I need to limit this behavior. Is there any way of limiting the access to previous page by browser back button in lift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to reliably stop the user from returning to the URL, but you can stop them from invoking the action more than once.  Take a look at `S.oneShot`.  From the Scala Doc:

> All functions created inside the oneShot scope will only be called
>   once and their  results will be cached and served again if the same
>   function is invoked

If you wrap the function that occurs when the button is pressed, even if the user does return to the page and click the button a second time, the body of the function shouldn't be invoked again.